# How to redirect to a PartialViewResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I redirect to a PartialViewResult?  I am having the error message:

> Error 1   'MvcUI.Controllers.ExpenseController.SaveAuthorization(string)': not all code paths return a value

```
public ActionResult SaveAuthorization(string ExpenseID)
     {

         RedirectToAction("AuthorizeEmployee");             
     }

     public PartialViewResult AuthorizeEmployee()
     {
         AuthorizeExpenseModel model = new AuthorizeExpenseModel(null, 0, "All");
         return PartialView("AuthorizeExpense_Details", model);
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put

```
return RedirectToAction("AuthorizeEmployee");
```

in your SaveAuthorization action